# Want to search text from a group of words and then sum in excel

Tags: excel, sum, conditional-statements, formula

I have a data as below -

```
Name        Amount
John Martha 20
John ABS    30
Man XYZ     10
```

Now, I want excel to search John from all rows and sum the value against it.

For example - John - 50

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to sum all values in column `B` where corresponding value in column `A` *contains substring* `John`, use this one:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"*John*",B1:B10)
```

If you'd like to sum all values in column `B` where corresponding value in column `A` *starts* from `John`, use this one:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"John *",B1:B10)
```

in both formulas range `A1:A10` contains names and `B1:B10` - amount